# How to check, that row of which section have been tapped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In a normal table with multiple section, (that I did through the delegate to define section), now in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` it starts with initial for every section. Now how can i check `row` from which section have been tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **`didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`** simple place the following:

`NSLog(@"SECTION: %i  ROW: %i",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);`

Answer (score 1):

`Indexpath` consists of `section` and `row` members. So you can use the property and get the section `yourindexpath.section` for row `yourindexpath.row`.

Answer (score 1):

in table view delegate you can use

indexPath.section;
    indexPath.row
to find section and row in that section